# Sql JOINs... Multiple or OR?

Tags: sql, performance, join, query-optimization

So to start I will say that I work for a company that likes to micro optimize (and with good reason). What I need to figure out is if there is any performance increase / decrease in the use of 2 joins, or 1 join with an `OR` on it.

This isn't a perfect example but it should get the point across. So for instance you have these 3 tables:

```
dbo.CUSTOMER1
 - CustomerId
 - CustomerName

dbo.CUSTOMER2
 - CustomerId
 - CustomerFauxId
 - CustomerName

dbo.CUSTOMERINFO
 - CustomerId
 - CustomerData
```

Now you need to join the tables and see if they have data in either table. Which method is going to be better from a performance stand point, or is there even a difference in the two?

This first example is how the query is currently written... Seems wasteful to me.

```
SELECT c1.CustomerId

FROM dbo.CUSTOMER1 c1

JOIN dbo.CUSTOMER2 c2
ON c1.CustomerId = c2.CustomerId

JOIN dbo.CUSTOMERINFO ci
ON ci.CustomerId = c1.CustomerId;

JOIN dbo.CUSTOMERINFO ci1
ON ci2.CustomerId = c2.CustomerFauxId;
```

I am looking to update to something along these lines...

```
SELECT c1.CustomerId

FROM dbo.CUSTOMER1 c1

JOIN dbo.CUSTOMER2 c2
ON c1.CustomerId = c2.CustomerId

JOIN dbo.CUSTOMERINFO ci
ON ci.CustomerId = c1.CustomerId
    OR ci.CustomerId = c2.CustomerFauxId;
```

Comment: You aren't `join`ing the tables at all. do you see that? the `join` condition is missing.

Comment: I.e. a cross join is performed.

Comment: @vkp You are correct. I was dealing with something else while writing that. Dumb, dumb. Check again, please.

Comment: OR is usually contraindicated, it is one of the slowest constructions especially in a join. And of course you should not under any circumstance be using select * as you are returning the joins filed multiple times and that is wasteful of network resources.

Comment: Do not ever consider trying to make SQL code more elegant, the things that look the worst are often the better performers. Only change code like this if you have a performance problem and can prove the new method is a better performer. NEVER CHANGE SQL CODE TO MAKE IT LOOK PRETTIER (other than formatting where the actual code doesn't change).

Comment: @HLGEM *Sigh... Okay, good to know about the OR but this is literally spewed code for example purposes. The real thing has about 30 required columns returned and that's it. I will update the example to avoid getting that comment again though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use query execution plan feature in SQLServer to get performance details of your query.

Answer (score 1):

They do not return the same result in the first place. In the first case You return customers where both `CustomerFauxId` and `CustomerId` exist in `CUSTOMERINFO` table. In the second case You return customers where `CustomerFauxId` or `CustomerId` exist and You can get the same customer twice when both exist.

There is also something fishy about the fact You join CUSTOMER1 and CUSTOMER2 on primary key. It is hard to tell without broader view, but I would strogly recommend to focus on schema design and proper indexing before doing any micro optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

The only logic query I can think of is:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.CUSTOMER c JOIN
     dbo.CUSTOMERINFO ci
     ON c.CustomerId = Ci.CustomerId
WHERE c.CustomerId IN (@Customer1, @Customer2);
```

With indexes on `CustomerId` in both tables, it is hard for me to think of a more performant version.

If you wanted the data for the two customers in additional columns, then you would consider the two-`JOIN` version.